# color code bootstrap buttons customization in javascript array list

Tags: javascript, css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3, colors

I would like to customize my buttons with bootstrap btn-success (green) and btn-danger (red) for specific array of buttons.
In this case, I would like excel to be green and pdf to be red.

My code to generate the buttons is as follows:

```
    var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(datatable, {
        buttons: [
            { 
                extend:'excelHtml5',
                footer: true,
                title: exportTitle(),
                messageTop: exportInfo()                    
            },
            { 
                extend:'pdf',
                footer: true ,
                title: exportTitle(),
                messageTop: exportInfo()
            }
        ]
    }).container().appendTo($("#divbuttons"))
    $("#divbuttons").find('button').removeClass()
    $("#divbuttons").find('button').addClass("btn btn-primary report_date") <-- here is where I set the css but it applies to both the buttons. How can I specifically say excel is btn-success and pdf is btn-danger
```

Currently it looks like that with the code above.

[image]

Here is the generated html code in the browser inspect

[image]

How can I specifically color code the buttons for excel is btn-success and pdf is btn-danger ?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily loop through the array of buttons.

Create a array that looks something like this:

```js
let buttons = [
 {
  name: "Find"
  class: "btn-primary"
 },
 {
  name: "Excel",
  class: "btn-success"
 },
 {
  name: "PDF"
  class: "btn-danger"
 }
]

for(const button in buttons) {
 $("#divbuttons").find('button').addClass(`btn ${button.class} report_date`)
}
```

This will just loop through the array and add the property `button.class` to the class name.

Comment: it doesnt work. I put this in the look ->  console.log(button.class); it says undefined

Comment: @Axil create a id on each button that are different, then add that id as an property to each object inside the array. Then you can do something like 

 $(#`${buttton.id`}).addClass(`btn ${button.class} report_date`)